# Hot to create difference Stream using Kafka Streams in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream

I'm trying to create a "Difference" stream from a KStream in Kafka Java.

I have an Input Stream where the values are a set of Doubles V0 … Vn. The Output stream should calculate the difference between V0 - 0, V1 – V0, V2 – V1 … Vn –Vn-1.

My first idea was to do something like this:

```
    KStream<String, Double> stream = builder.stream(TOPIC)

    KTable<String, Double> difference = stream.groupByKey().reduce(
            (oldValue, newValue) -> {
              return newValue - oldValue
            }
    ).toStream()
```

Lets say I have a KStream input with the following values:

```
Key  -> Value
"A1" -> 2 
"B2" -> 4
"A1" -> 6
"A1" -> 10
"B2" -> 13 
"A1" -> 7
```

I would like to create a new Stream output with the following values:

```
Key  -> Value
"A1" ->  2  (2-0  =  2) 
"B2" ->  4  (4-0  =  4)
"A1" ->  4  (6-2  =  4)
"A1" ->  4  (10-6 =  4)
"B2" ->  9  (13-4 =  9)
"A1" -> -3  (7-10 = -3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
        stream.groupByKey().aggregate(Diff::new, new Aggregator<String, Double, Diff>() {

        @Override
        public Diff apply(String key, Double newValue, Diff aggregate) {
            Double difference = newValue - aggregate.getLastValue();
            aggregate.setDifference(difference);
            aggregate.setLastValue(newValue);
            return aggregate;
        }
        }).mapValues(new ValueMapper<Diff, Double>() {

        @Override
        public Double apply(Diff value) {
            return value.getDifference();
        }

    }).toStream().to("diff");
```

where

```
public class Diff {

  private Double lastValue = 0d;

  private Double difference = 0d;
  //getters and setters
  // ...
}
```